# Fsharp WorldBankData keep throwing FS0039 error

Tags: f#, f#-data, fslab

I am playing with FsLab and ran into issues when I was playing example from here:

https://fslab.org/getting-started/

```
open FSharp.Data

let wb = WorldBankData.GetDataContext()
let cz = wb.Countries.``Czech Republic``.Indicators
let eu = wb.Countries.``European Union``.Indicators
```

The error is
`Error  FS0039  The type 'Countries' does not define the field, constructor or member 'Czech Republic'.`

Any clue would be appreciated.

In case it helps, here is the package dependencies

[image]

Comment: Looks like related to [this issue](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/1324), the corresponding type provider is broken. Sad, yet at least this isn't related to FsLab itself, so you can go play with other `FSharp.Data` [stuff](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/index.html) :)

Comment: Thanks @psfinaki, that must be it, the weird thing is autocompletion still found Countries as I type but won't work with any specific country name.